# Mariabackup FATAL ERROR - Was only able to copy log from x to y, not z, try increasing innodb_log_file_size

Tags: mariadb

I run the mariabackup command like this:

```
sudo -u mysql mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/opt/mariadb_backup/full_backup  --user=root --password=root --host=localhost 2>&1
```

And i get this error

```
[01] 2023-09-15 10:45:57         ...done
[00] 2023-09-15 10:45:57 Waiting for log copy thread to read lsn 735453
[00] 2023-09-15 10:45:58 >> log scanned up to (734409)
[00] 2023-09-15 10:45:59 >> log scanned up to (734409)
[00] 2023-09-15 10:46:00 >> log scanned up to (734409)
[00] 2023-09-15 10:46:01 >> log scanned up to (734409)
[00] 2023-09-15 10:46:02 >> log scanned up to (734409)
[00] FATAL ERROR: 2023-09-15 10:46:02 Was only able to copy log from 734393 to 734409, not 735453; try increasing innodb_log_file_size
silver@silverbox:/opt/mariadb_backup$
```

What is wrong and how do i fix this ?

***Update

I restarted server and the error went away.

`service mariadb restart`

Don't know how.

Comment: Did you increase [innodb_log_file_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size)?

Comment: no, i did not change any settings, dont even know what those settings are about.